# Programmatically moving UILabel not working

Tags: ios, swift

I am having trouble changing the position of my UILabel. I can change font color and background etc but its position doesn't seem to move no matter what I try. Any help would be appreciated. Im also not using storyboard at all.

I'm fairly new to this so I'm probably missing something very obvious. I have googled and tried anything I thought applied but haven't had any luck.

View Builder:

```
import UIKit

class StandMapView: UIView {

    var titleLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    var standMapImage: UIImageView = UIImageView()
    var hotspotImage: UIImageView = UIImageView()
    var hotspotTitleLabelArray: [UILabel] = []
    var hotspotTextArray: [UITextView] = []

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func bind(standMap: StandMap, hotspots: [Hotspot]) {
        titleLabel.text = standMap.title
        standMapImage.image = UIImage(named: standMap.mapImage)
        hotspotImage.image = UIImage(named:standMap.hotspotImage)
        for hotspot in hotspots {
            let hotspotTitle = UILabel()
            let hotspotText = UITextView()
            hotspotTitle.text = hotspot.title
            hotspotText.text = hotspot.text
            hotspotTitleLabelArray.append(hotspotTitle)
            hotspotTextArray.append(hotspotText)
        }
    }

    private func setupView() {

        let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
        self.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)

        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        standMapImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        hotspotImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        titleLabel.sizeToFit()

        titleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: screenWidth/2, y: 30, width: 0, height: 0)
        titleLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        addSubview(titleLabel)

    }

}
```

View Controller:

```
import UIKit

    class StandMapViewController: UIViewController {

        var standMap: StandMap!
        var hotspots: [Hotspot] = []

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            Hotspot.all { hotspot in
                hotspot.forEach(self.assignHotspotVariable)
            }

            StandMap.build {standMap in
                standMap.forEach(self.assignStandMapVariable)
            }

            viewForStandMap(standMap, hotspots: hotspots)

        }

        private func assignStandMapVariable(standMap: StandMap) {
            self.standMap = standMap
        }

        private func assignHotspotVariable(hotspot: Hotspot) {
            hotspots.append(hotspot)
        }

        private func viewForStandMap(standMap: StandMap, hotspots: [Hotspot]) {
            let standMapView = StandMapView(frame: CGRectZero)
            standMapView.bind(standMap, hotspots: hotspots)
            view.addSubview(standMapView)
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you are adding label to your view you should also setup its frame in it not by taking whole screen sizes

Comment: Please post less code; only that what matters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the position of the label, you need to change the origin x and y

```
 titleLabel.frame.origin.x = 0.0 // put your value
 titleLabel.frame.origin.y = 0.0 // put your value
 self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Try to add   self.view.layoutIfNeeded()    after setting origin

Comment: that hasnt made it move either. i cant figure out why it wont move

Comment: i added exactly what you said, but replaced the values with 200, putting it underneath: titleLabel.sizeToFit()

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `AutoLayout`, do following:

1. set outlet for constraint of `UILable` that you want to change.
2. Then change constant of that constraint as per your need.

   `e.g: xPosOfLable.constant = x`

Answer (score 0):

If your label has constraints with `Autolayout` in storyboard, you must disable constraints to move the frame.  Try using

```
titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
```

Hope this may solve your issue.

Comment: im not using storyboard at all

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this using snapkit cocoa pod to make the constraints and then adding the subview before declaring these constraints.

Thanks for everyones help.

Heres the changes i made to the setupView function:

```
        private func setupView() {

            titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            standMapImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            hotspotImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            titleLabel.textAlignment = .Center
            titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
            titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            addSubview(titleLabel)

            titleLabel.snp_makeConstraints { make in
                make.topMargin.equalTo(snp_topMargin).multipliedBy(60)
                make.centerX.equalTo(snp_centerX)
            }



        }
```